# TMemoryStream в потоке 1 из 10 ошибка

Tags: delphi, многопоточность, потоки-данных

Фрейм расположен на 1 главной форме, приведённый код работает в потоке, должен сохранять картинку в папку ,но иногда перестаёт перезаписывать картинку и останавливается.

```
  Fix: TMemoryStream;
  png: TPNGObject;

begin
      Fix := TMemoryStream.Create;
      png := TPNGObject.Create;
      Form1.Frame11.idhttp1.Get('http://www.work.net/captcha/captcha-st/captcha.php?sid=' + sid, Fix);
      Fix.Position := 0;
      png.LoadFromStream(Fix);
      png.SaveToFile('accounts\akk' + Form1.Frame11.label1.Caption + '/' + '1.png');
      Fix.Free;
      png.Free;
end;
```

Comment: а отлаживать пробовали? Где конкретно останавливается, применительно к этому доп.потоку?

Comment: @kami уверен, что поток не "останавливается", а выбрасывает Exception и прерывается

Comment: @Igor давайте потелепатируем :) Где? Я вижу только одно место -  если вернется не 200 ОК. Ну и путь к файлу сохранения странный.

Comment: Вероятная причина - несинхронизиронный доступ к визуальным элементам из главного и второстепенного потоков: `Form1.Frame11.label1.Caption`.

Comment: @Igor кстати возможно. Что я сделал. - Я написал код потока в фрейме. После я скопировал этот же фрейм на форме и получил Фрейм 2(по имени) и так я сделал 10 фреймов. После чего у меня в Uses естественно 1 фрейм н ов нём прописаны потоки от первого фрейма до 10того, лишь с одним изменением Form1.Frame12,Form1.Frame13 и т.д. Может быть сделать для каждого фрейма свой Uses и прописать в каждом отдельный поток ? Не может ли быть так что все они работают через Form1.Frame11?

Comment: @kami я не умею пользоваться отладчиком, начал программировать месяца два назад, впервые сделал поток и столкнулся с проблемами.

Comment: `Не может ли быть так что все они работают через Form1.Frame11?` - так вы же явно указали - Form1.Frame11. Было бы странно, если бы вместо явно указанного шло обращение к чему-то другому :)

Comment: @Igor Оппа... почему-то был уверен, что Label просто хранит свой Caption  в приватной переменной с простым геттером, в этом случае основной/не основной поток было бы всё равно. А там оказывается всё сложно, аж через два сообщения... Может есть какой-нибудь канонический ответ про работу с потоками?

Comment: @kami - Так вроде, классика - не лезть в компоненты форм напрямую из второстепенных потоков - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize

Answer (score 1):

Проблема явно не в TMemoryStream. Это обычная последовательность байт (кусок памяти). Единственная ошибка, которая может тут возникнуть с TMemoryStream - это не хватка памяти.

Уязвимые места (необходимо обернуть в try except) :
1) idhttp1.Get - нет соединения и другие ошибки

2) png.LoadFromStream(Fix) -ошибка формата файла, данные переданы не полностью.

3) png.SaveToFile - конфликт доступа к файлу (два потока пытаются в один файл писать).  Ошибка записи в файл.

4) Желательно создать idhttp в коде, потому что может возникнуть конфликт 
обращения к ресурсам этого объекта. Один поток читает png, второй тоже читает. Что будет?

Отладчик может не помочь, а вот писать лог ошибки и смотреть ход работы процессов вполне стандартное решение.

Отладьте код без потока. Потом уже внутри него.

Answer (score 0):

Как уже писали в комментариях, проблема в `Form1.Frame11.idhttp1.Get(...`.

Правильно создавать компонент `idhttp` в каждом потоке свой. `TPNGObject` здесь вообще не нужен.

Упрощенный пример метода `Execute` такого потока:

```
var
  FileStream: TFileStream;
  idhttp: T{какой там у него тип}
begin
  FileStream := TFileStream.Create(FileName + '.png');
  try
    idhttp := T{какой там у него тип}.Create({что там ему надо?});
    try
      idhttp.Get('http://www.work.net/captcha/captcha-st/captcha.php?sid=' + sid, FileStream);
    finally
      idhttp.Free;
    end;
  finally  
    FileStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

А `FileName` и `sid` передавать каждому потоку параметрами в конструктор.